# What does the sentence mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning, phrases

Please help me figure out the meanings of the following sentence:

[But Apple tends to build in parameters on their devices so you’re watching with most of those variables dialled in.](https://apps.apple.com/us/story/id1484527615)

I am confused by the phrases "build in" and "dialled in" here.

The text is from the description of the show The Mandalorian, which is the first-ever Star Wars live-action TV series.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

The creator of the program is being interviewed. He is talking about how he controls the way his program will appear to viewers. He says that when the program is presented on different devices (computers or television sets), the appearance may change due to different settings, such as brightness and contrast, that the viewer can change.

He simplifies his efforts to control the program's appearance by designing the program for Apple devices, because these are less adjustable than other devices.
 In that sentence, "built in" has the same meaning as "dialled in". It means that Apple has predetermined the video settings and the viewer can't adjust them.